# Get context values into CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I migrated a cloudformation template into cdk. However the parameters weren't migrated as well.I did that by adding the values to the context field in the cdk.json file. However, when I run cdk deploy, I get an error saying values from the migrated template are still missing. Below are the code snippets

```json
  "context": {
    "params": {
      "pProjectName" : "OVERRIDE",
      "pSNSRoleStackName" : "OVERRIDE",
      "pExternalId" : "OVERRIDE",
      "pRefreshTokenValidity": "OVERRIDE",
      "pSourceEmailArn": "OVERRIDE",
      "pEmail": "OVERRIDE",
      "pStageName": "dev",
      "pMerchantUserDomainName": "merchant-user-dev-liberty",
      "pOperatorDomainName": "operator-dev-liberty",
      "pPartnerDomainName": "partner-dev-liberty",
      "pMerchantClientPaymentDomainName": "merchantclient-payment-dev-liberty",
      "pMerchantClientUerManagementDomainName": "merchantclient-usermanagement-dev-liberty",
      "pCognitoAuthStackName": "liberty-cog-ovrride-dev"
    }
  }
```

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as cfn_inc from 'aws-cdk-lib/cloudformation-include';
// import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export class ClickcommerceAaaStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here

    const params = this.node.tryGetContext('params');

    const cfnTemplate = new cfn_inc.CfnInclude(this, 'Template', { 
      templateFile: 'UserAndIdentityPool.yaml',
    });
```

> ❌  ClickcommerceAaaStack failed: Error: The following CloudFormation Parameters are missing a value: pSNSRoleStackName, pExternalId, pRefreshTokenValidity, pEmail, pSourceEmailArn, pPartnerDomainName, pMerchantClientPaymentDomainName, pMerchantClientUerManagementDomainName, pMerchantUserDomainName, pOperatorDomainName, pCognitoAuthStackName

Successfully migrated the resource to CDK from cloudformation using the cnfInclude module.
I ran it with parameters within the construct, which was successful, however as a best practice, I would prefer having these variables in the cdk.json file as contexts then calling them into the construct that holds the migrated cloudformation template